# Limit HTTP VERBS on Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, http

I am trying to limit the use of certain HTTP verbs on my site.  I entered the following into my VirtualHost config file within the Directory element:

```
<Limit GET POST HEAD>
 Allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
 Deny from all
</Limit>
```

This seemed to work but with unexpected results:

I ran the following telnet/HTTP commands before and after this change,

```
open server 80
OPTIONS server/abs_path HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Telnet/1.0
Host: server
```

before the change I received a successful response with the Allowed headers.

After the change, however, I was expecting to receive a 405 'Method not allowed' response but rather I received a 403 'Access Forbidden' response.

What do I need to change in apache to return the 405 HTTP response?

Many thanks

Comment: Apache is returning 403 because you are using deny. Can try custom errors

Comment: How would I add a custom error to the Limit element?

Answer (score 4):

After three hours of reviewing the apache docs and testing, I found I can use the mod_rewrite to correctly respond to unwanted HTTP methods:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST 
RewriteRule .* /error/405.html [R=405,L]
```

Comment: Yes it's working on apache2.2 but i don't why `LimitExcept` parameter not working !